# using pd.DataFrame.apply to create multiple columns

Tags: pandas

My first question here!

I'm having some trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong here, trying to append columns to an existing pd.DataFrame object. Specifically, my original dataframe has n-many columns, and I want to use apply to append an additional 2n-many columns to it.  The problem seems to be that doing this via apply() doesn't work, in that if I try to append more than n-many columns, it falls over.  This doesn't make sense to me, and I was hoping somebody could either shed some light on to why I'm seeing this behaviour, or suggest a better approach.

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2))

def this_works(x):
    return 5 * x

def this_fails(x):
    return np.append(5 * x, 5 * x)

df.apply(this_works, 1)  # Two columns of output, as expected
df.apply(this_fails, 1)  # Unexpected failure...
```

Any ideas?  I know there are other ways to create the data columns, this approach just seemed very natural to me and I'm quite confused by the behaviour.

SOLVED!  CT Zhu's solution below takes care of this, my error arises from not properly returning  a pd.Series object in the above.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do a few different calculations on your `df` and put the resulting vectors together in one larger `DataFrame`, like in this example?:

```
In [39]:

print df

          0         1
0  0.718003  0.241216
1  0.580015  0.981128
2  0.477645  0.463892
3  0.948728  0.653823
4  0.056659  0.366104
5  0.273700  0.062131
6  0.151237  0.479318
7  0.425353  0.076771
8  0.317731  0.029182
9  0.543537  0.589783

In [40]:

print df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.hstack((x*5, x*6))), axis=1)

          0         1         2         3
0  3.590014  1.206081  4.308017  1.447297
1  2.900074  4.905639  3.480088  5.886767
2  2.388223  2.319461  2.865867  2.783353
3  4.743640  3.269114  5.692369  3.922937
4  0.283293  1.830520  0.339951  2.196624
5  1.368502  0.310656  1.642203  0.372787
6  0.756187  2.396592  0.907424  2.875910
7  2.126764  0.383853  2.552117  0.460624
8  1.588656  0.145909  1.906387  0.175091
9  2.717685  2.948917  3.261222  3.538701
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI in this trivial case you can do `5 * df` !

I think the issue here is that np.append *flattens* the Series:

```
In [11]: np.append(df[0], df[0])
Out[11]:
array([ 0.33145275,  0.14964056,  0.86268119,  0.17311983,  0.29618537,
        0.48831228,  0.64937305,  0.03353709,  0.42883925,  0.99592229,
        0.33145275,  0.14964056,  0.86268119,  0.17311983,  0.29618537,
        0.48831228,  0.64937305,  0.03353709,  0.42883925,  0.99592229])
```

what you want is it to create four columns (isn't it?). The axis=1 means that you are doing this row-wise (i.e. x is the row which is a Series)...

In general you want apply to return either:

- a single value, or
- a Series (with unique index).

---

Saying that I kinda thought the following may work (to get four columns):

```
In [21]: df.apply((lambda x: pd.concat([x[0] * 5, x[0] * 5], axis=1)), axis=1)
TypeError: ('cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object', u'occurred at index 0')

In [22]: df.apply(lambda x: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), axis=1)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10,), indices imply (10, 2)

In [23]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]), axis=1)  # works
```

*Maybe I expected the first to raise about non-unique index... but I was surprised that the second failed.*

Comment: why are you showing using apply anyhow? this should just be column assignment, no?

Comment: @andy-hayden Trivial example is for behavior demonstration purposes only, what I'm trying to do is treat each row as a vector and create a larger vector that is best stored in the same row--hence the axis=1 flag.

Comment: @Jeff Maybe, but as I've mentioned this seemed the most natural way of doing things for my actual application.

Comment: @tim, you need to have the callable inside `.apply()` to return a `Series` as @AndyHayden pointed out. Also, use `np.hstack` instead of `.append`.

Comment: @CTZhu I don't get why the concat example doesn't work (it ought to return a Series) ?

Comment: @AndyHayden, I guess it is because `x[0]` is going to be the cell value (therefore one of `numpy.int`, `numpy.float`, `object`, etc), and `concat` fails? But `df.apply(lambda x: pd.concat((x*5, x*6)), axis=1)` will work giving almost the same result as `df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.hstack((x*5, x*6))), axis=1)`, except the column index are `0 1 0 1` instead of `0 1 2 3`. So I guess my initial feeling is not right, `Series` is not absolutely required.

Comment: @CTZhu ! No idea why I missed that. Thanks!